# Did a broadcast of the US National Anthem in the 60's use subliminal messaging?

Tags: united-states, government, television

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDsI-zk6gfE#t=207), by "Truthstream Media" tells us the following:

- As we watch Television, we become susceptible to subliminal messaging because we stop emitting alpha waves and start emitting beta waves
- In between the dissolve cuts for the subtitles on the video, messages such as "Government is God" are subliminally shown.

I'm most interested in the latter, where in the video the original video is slowed down. They cite this video, but is there any proof proving that these sign-offs really did contain these messages? [The accompanying article links](http://truthstreammedia.com/1960s-subliminal-video-of-national-anthem-hides-mkultra-message-to-obey-government/) to one or two amateur sources, and talks about 60's and 70's CIA Brain-control missions ("MKUltra") but again I see no primary, strong sources.

Comment: I can debunk the claim that the messages are subliminal: if you know what you're looking for, the "hidden messages" in the full-speed video are quite easy to see.  Whether this video was actually broadcast in the 1960s is a different matter.

Comment: @Mark: I think discussing the definition of 'subliminal' and whether 'subliminal advertising' works (while they could make good Skeptics.SE questions) are off-topic here. We should stick to "Was this message embedded in films that went to air?"

Comment: The video claims the opposite of your question: That while watching TV people "switch to alpha waves".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't trust it to be true: it's almost certainly a fake.

1. The original is likely here and has no messages (but better colors!):

   [image: original still image]

   http://www.fuzzymemories.tv/index.php?c=3104 -- It's an uncut segment, jump to 3m43s for the anthem)

   Note that the clip *seems* original and is *clearly* from the 80's.
2. A 3rd party analysis, which includes a slow down, is available on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PxDZI-6O-w
3. It contains the signature of the [original uploader (Naomi)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMZ_rQKAy7c), which I found by using Google's advanced search (this is also confirmed by [infowars](http://www.infowars.com/real-or-hoax-1960s-subliminal-national-anthem-video-says-obey-government/))

   > BUY MKNAOMI

   The account is an [anonymous account](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-isc8o96riPqCNGxheCWrw), has only uploaded that video, contains a clear reference to its secret contents but does not mention them. If the uploader was not aware of the contents, then it would be uncanny that their username coincides with the contents. If they were aware, then why not mention in the description? My speculation is because they wanted to play the "discovered by chance" card.

   > I salvaged this reel of film from a TV station that used to sign of with it during the 1960s.
4. Another video debunk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vj5b_z5kGvg&index=198&list=PLojvTRr2YYfbQ7mDoEVoh_8AHBn4KYCMd)

## Conclusion

While anything is possible, and showing an *undoctored* copy does not indeed "prove" that the example is a fake... an anoyomous upload on youtube certainly does not "prove", at all, that there was a subliminal message in this clip in the 60's. At the *very least* a third party analysis of the original master is necessary to provide convincing proof that this could be the case.

Comment: That first link isn't available anymore, so I'm gonna have to disregard your opinion on it tbh.

Comment: @MarcusJ what link doesn't work, I just verified them all...

Comment: The first didn't work for me, but wiki images aren't showing up so maybe my browser is messed up.